# Как выполнить асинхронную операцию с возвращаемым результатом фоном (то есть проигнорировав результат) в C#

Tags: c#, async-await

У меня есть асинхронная функция, она возвращает результат. Иногда он мне нужен, иногда нет. В описанном ниже случае, как раз нет. Вот код:

```
var ignore = _applicationRepo.UpdateAsync(application);
```

если написать

```
_applicationRepo.UpdateAsync(application);
```

тогда IDE пишет варнинг `warning this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call complited.`

То есть, пока вызвавший метод выполняется, выполняется и мой `UpdateAsync`? А как только вызвавший завершится, `UpdateAsync` может тоже завершиться, так сказать, на полуслове, не выполнившись? Верно? Или как это понимать?

И самый главный вопрос, я могу просто проигнорировать результат, не создавая "игнор" переменные и в то же время, быть уверенным, что метод выполнится фоном, даже если вызывающий уже отработал? Есть ли какой-нибудь красивый способ это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начиная с C# 7.0 в языке появилась такая возможность, как [Discards](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards).

```
_ = _applicationRepo.UpdateAsync(application);
```

Используя знак подчёркивания мы явно даём понять, что результат не используется. И память под него не выделяется.

Comment: Ого! Спасибо! Попробую.

Answer (score 2):

> То есть, пока вызвавший метод выполняется, выполняется и мой
>   UpdateAsync? А как только вызвавший завершится, UpdateAsync может тоже
>   завершиться, так сказать, на полуслове, не выполнившись? Верно? Или
>   как это понимать?

Нет, .NET среда не может просто так завершить любой метод, ведь это как минимум небезопасно. Как только вы вызываете `UpdateAsync` объект `Task` добавляется в пул, и остается там до того времени, пока не выполнится до конца.

Красивого способа как игнорировать результат нет. Можете отключить предупреждение компилятора:

```
#pragma warning disable 4014
    _applicationRepo.UpdateAsync();
#pragma warning restore 4014
```

Ну или если у вас таких вызовов много, тогда можно один раз прописать в файле `#pragma warning disable 4014` и не возобновлять его.

Comment: То есть, если я просто не буду обращать внимания на этот варнинг, не укажу `await` то  .NET достанет из своего пула мой `UpdateAsync` и даже после завершения вызывающего метода он будет выполняться фоном, и пусть он ужасно долги и трудоемкий? Так?

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak async не обязательно подразумевает обработку в пуле. Выполнение зайдет внутрь UpdateAsync, и дальше внутрь до первого await, результат для которого не будет получен синхронно. Потом резко выпрыгнет наверх, на строчку после вызова UpdateAsync и продолжит идти по вызывающему методу. А вот весь остаток после внутреннего async, и все остатки методов выше, вплоть до остатка UpdateAsync, будут поставлены на выполнение в пул после завершения асинхронной операции.

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak всё верно, не важно насколько `UpdateAsync` долгий или трудоемкий, он выполнится до конца. Если вкратце - то `await` указывает на то, что нужно ждать завершения. Не указали `await`,значит не ждете, но метод все равно выполнится

Answer (score 2):

Судя по комментариям, вы не совсем верно представляете себе, как работает async-await. Он не запускает метод в фоне, как вы ожидаете. Он просто прерывает выполнение на время асинхронной операции.

Например, у вас есть следующий код

```
async static Task<bool> SomeInnerMethodAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start of SomeInnerMethodAsync");
    // тут какая-то долгая сетевая или дисковая операция
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("End of SomeInnerMethodAsync");
    return true;
}
async static Task<bool> UpdateAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start of UpdateAsync");
    bool result = await SomeInnerMethodAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("End of UpdateAsync");
    return result;
}

async static Task OuterMethod()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start of OuterMethod");
    await UpdateAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("End of OuterMethod");
}
```

При выполнении произойдет следующее:

```
Start of OuterMethod
Start of UpdateAsync
Start of SomeInnerMethodAsync
<ожидание>
End of SomeInnerMethodAsync
End of UpdateAsync
End of OuterMethod
```

Т.е. выполнение дошло внутрь до вызова, который действительно не может завершиться синхронно (`Task.Delay`), и только тогда остановилось. По завершению `Task.Delay` выполнение продолжилось на потоке из пула.

Если вы уберете `await`, то вместо приостановки управление перейдет к остатку `OuterMethod` сразу же, а остатки внутренних методов будут выполнены на потоке из пулла:

```
async static Task OuterMethod()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start of OuterMethod");
    UpdateAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("End of OuterMethod");
}
```

Вывод:

```
Start of OuterMethod
Start of UpdateAsync
Start of SomeInnerMethodAsync
End of OuterMethod, продолжение выполнения кода, вызвашего OuterMethod
<пауза, вывод из потока в пуле:>
End of SomeInnerMethodAsync
End of UpdateAsync
```

Если вам нужно именно запустить метод в фоне - используйте `Task.Run()`, а не async-await.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала ответ на главный вопрос: 
`await _applicationRepo.UpdateAsync(application);`
таким образом результат может быть проигнорирован. В C/C++/C# функция может возвращать значение, но мы отнюдь не обязаны его получать.

Теперь про остальное: вызывающий метод не завершится, пока не будут завершены все функции, предварённые оператором `await` в нём. Вызывающий метод отработает, но не вернёт значение, пока не дождётся всех `await`. (wait – ждать).

Comment: Так это то что мне как раз не нужно. Или я что-то не понимаю. Мне нужно просто фоном запустить мой метод, забыть о результате, идти дальше, а он пусть там обновляет уже что-то.

Comment: Что в Вашем понимании "идти дальше"? Выйти из вызывающего метода? Если так, то сделайте его тоже асинхронным и вставьте `await` на том месте, где вызывается он. Возможно, это поможет.

Comment: "Идти дальше" в моем понимании, это не ждать выполнения `UpdateAsync` а перейти на следующую строчку. `UpdateAsync` работает фоном. Да он возвращает результат, но в данном случае, мне он абсолютно не важен.

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak тогда оберните вызов Вашего асинхронного метода в ещё один асинхронный метод, возвращающий `void` и вызывайте его на месте предыдущего без `await`. Однако в этом случае, как Вы и говорили, выполнение асинхронного метода может не завершиться, если программа завершится раньше. Это аналог `detach` в C++.